# Compare 3 variables and echo the winner most voted

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have 3 queries to a MySQL database but I will make it simple like this example:

```
$var1 = "354";
$var2 = "980";
$var3 = "27";
```

I need to compare in some way these 3 variables and display only the largest- in this example, the $var2 with value 980.

To do this I run:

```
$biggest = max($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Now I need to display the following echo example:

```
the variable $var2 is the winner with 980 votes
```

How can that be achieved?

This is how the values of the variables are assigned:

```
$var1=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($datacenter, 
"SELECT COUNT(comite) FROM votos WHERE `comite` = '1'"));
$var2=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($datacenter, 
"SELECT COUNT(comite) FROM votos WHERE `comite` = '2'"));
$var3=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($datacenter, 
"SELECT COUNT(comite) FROM votos WHERE `comite` = '3'"));
```

Comment: Any time you end up using variables named 1,2,3, etc, it likely means you should be using an array.

Comment: any example to see ?

Comment: `$vars = [ 1 => 354, 2 => 980, 3 => 27 ]; max($vars);`  Doesn't solve your problem, but will get you closer...  You'll then need to get the corresponding key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually be better off with a completely different approach - let mySQL do the heavy lifting:

```
$result = mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT `comite`, COUNT(`comite`) `count` FROM `votos` GROUP BY `comite` ORDER BY COUNT(`comite`) DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "The winner is ".$row['comite']." with ".$row['count']." votes";
```